# How can service be notified of driver uninstall?

Tags: c++, service, driver

I have a driver that is installed via INF file.
A service will also be started automatically when the driver is installed.

All binary files will be inside `%SystemRoot%\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository` upon successful install.

Now when I uninstall my driver from device manager>System devices check "Delete the driver software for this device"

[image]

My service will receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` form Service Control Manager. After receiving this event, I want to call `DeleteService()` to delete the service and its corresponding registry entries.

However, realized I can't just call `DeleteService()` immediately because it is possible that the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` from SCM is triggered by stopping the service manually, service must not be deleted in this case.

So I wonder how can I determine from my service that my driver got uninstalled so that i know when to call `DeleteService()` properly.

Here's what i got so far after i 'google' for a couple of hours:

- In some versions of windows, binary files are deleted immediately in `DriverStore\FileRepository` after uninstall just before service gets notified with `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`. I can check if driver binaries are deleted and if so, it is uninstalled.
- Adding `SPSVCINST_STOPSERVICE` in `DelService` section of INF will send a stop event in service when driver is uninstalled. But again, i can't know if the stop event is coming from manual stop or uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I created a separate service that monitors when binary files are deleted in `DriverStore\FileRepository` by `FindNextChangeNotification(m_handle);`. Once it detects delete, then I call `DeleteService()`